# $_POST is empty, even without changes to php.ini?

Tags: php, html, post, xampp

I've been following this tutorial to learn php so I have a html script:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="registernext.php">
            <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="15" maxlength="20" value="megaman"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="register"></p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the php script:

```
<?php

echo file_get_contents('php://input');
$test = $_POST["username"];
echo " testname = (".$_POST["username"].")";

?>
```

But what I get when I run it is:

```
username=megaman testname = ()
```

My problem is that the name (megaman) get's sent to POST but doesn't show up in the php script.

Also, I haven't made any changes to the php.ini as oppose to some others that had problems when they did so.

I don't know if this helps but I'm running this via xampp (fresh download).

Help would be deeply appreciated, as searching for solutions haven't been successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try replacing all the PHP code with

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

submit the form. if anything comes up then nothing is wrong with PHP.

Comment: array(2) { ["username"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(8) "register" } is what came up. Does that mean that the problem isn't with php?

Comment: I'm so stupid, when I wrote what you said I realised that there was some other funky code that interfered. Thanks and note to self: never copy paste code...